# Как типизировать item в map React при рендинге компонентов

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Интерфейс

```
export interface IMovie {
  nameRu: string;
  rating: number;
  posterUrlPreview: string;
  year: number
  filmId: number;
  [key: string]: any;
}
```

Компонент

```
import { useTypedSelector } from '../../hooks/useTypedSelector';
import { IMovie, IMoviesState } from '../../types/movies';
import MovieCard from '../MovieCard/MovieCard';
import styles from './styles.module.css';

const MoviesList: React.FC = () => {
  const moviesList = useTypedSelector((state) => state.movies.movies);
  console.log('moviesList:', moviesList)

  return (
    <ul className={styles.list}>
      {moviesList.map((movie: IMovie) => (

        <li key={movie.filmId} className={styles.listItem}>
          <MovieCard
            nameRu={movie.nameRu}
            rating={movie.rating}
            posterUrlPreview={movie.posterUrlPreview}
            type={movie.type}
            year={movie.year}
          />
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default MoviesList;
```

TypeScript ругается на movie в map при рендинге компонетов. Почему? В movie попадает объект описанный в интерфейсе

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это объект который попадает в movie
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хук

```
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { rootState } from "../store";

export const useTypedSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<rootState> = useSelector;
```

Стор

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  movies: moviesReducer,
  loader: handleLoader,
});

export const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

export type rootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>
```

Comment: Проблема в `useTypedSelector` - он возвращает не тот тип

Comment: У вас элемент movieList'a уже типизирован, удалите в callback функции map'а тип аргумента `movie: IMovie` и наведите на аргумент мышкой, редактор вам покажет, какой у него тип.

Comment: Я добавил в первый пост Хук и Стор. Я понимаю это так: хук useTypedSelector должен возвращать тип соответствующий initialState...в moviesList он и попадает. Что в нем не правильно?

Comment: @xydope удалил из map IMovie и навел мышкой....мне показало parametr movie: {} ...то есть пустой объект...его разве не надо типизировать?

Comment: @qweezz у вас, судя по всему, фильмы должны находится в `movieList.array`, но вы мап делаете по всему стейту, а не по массиву `IMovie`. Кроме этого, как пишет ide, в вашем стейте `movieList.array` типизирован как `{}[]` (массив объектов), а должен быть типизирован как `IMovie []`

Comment: @xydope разобрался...вы правильно сказали что стейт типизирован как {}[], а надо IMovie[] ...сделал и все заработало